# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of a Specific Integral Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I'm working on the following linear algebra problem: Let $R[x]_n$ be the space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$. Find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the operator $\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)dt$ on the space $R[x]_n$.

Here's my attempt at a solution:

Define the operator $T$ by $Tf(x) = \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)dt$ , where $f(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_1x + a_0 \in R[x]_n$. Then $Tf(x) = \frac{1}{x}(\frac{a_n}{n+1}x^{n+1} + \frac{a_{n-1}}{n}x^n + ... + \frac{a_1}{2}x^2 + \frac{a_0}{1}x^1)$

$= \frac{a_n}{n+1}x^n + \frac{a_{n-1}}{n}x^{n-1} + ... + \frac{a_1}{2}x + \frac{a_0}{1}x^0$.

We now find eigenvalues $\lambda$ of the operator $T$:

$Tf(x) = \lambda f(x)$         (where $f(x) \neq 0$)

$\Rightarrow$ $\frac{a_n}{n+1}x^n + \frac{a_{n-1}}{n}x^{n-1} + ... + \frac{a_1}{2}x + \frac{a_0}{1}x^0 = \lambda a_nx^n + \lambda a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + \lambda a_1x + \lambda a_0$

$\Rightarrow$ by matching up coefficients, $\frac{a_n}{n+1} = \lambda a_n , \frac{a_{n-1}}{n} = \lambda a_{n-1}, ... , \frac{a_0}{1} = \lambda a_0$.

This is the part where I get tripped up. Based on the $n+1$ above equations, it seems that it is impossible to find such a $\lambda$ that will simultaneously solve all $n+1$ equations. Thus, it seems that there are no eigenvalues, and therefore, no corresponding eigenvectors.

Would this be correct? Thanks a lot in advance math friends!

~Mo

Answer (score 2):

Hint: there are eigen values. If you take $a_i=1$ and all other $a_j=0$ you see that $\lambda =\frac 1 j$ is an eigen value for $1\leq j \leq n+1$. Now it shouldn't be difficult for you to show that these are the only eigen values. It is also easy to write down eigen functions corresponding to these eigen values.

Comment: Hi Kavi! Thanks for the reply. I believe I understand what you're saying - the only way it's possible that lambda is an eigenvalue is if the original polynomial only has one term a_ix^i ! And in this case, the eigenvalue is just 1/(i+1)! Thus, we get n eigenvalues - one for each polynomial f(x) = a_ix^i with degree i, where $1 < = i < = n$? And those polynomials f(x) there are exactly the eigenfunctions?

Comment: @MoBehzadKang Yes, what you are saying is right.